# Error deploying using Django mod_wsgi on Apache in Amazon AWS server

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

Using AWS micro instance with Redhat 7, default python 2.7.5, django 1.7. deploying simple mysite project throws below error.

**Forbidden**

You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Below is the simple procedure used to create django project and deploy it.

```
Using username "ec2-user".
Authenticating with public key "imported-openssh-key"
Last login: Fri Sep 26 10:43:08 2014 from 14.141.162.198
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-1-245 ~]$ mkdir django
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-1-245 ~]$ cd django
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-1-245 django]$ django-admin startproject mysite
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-1-245 django]$ cd mysite/
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-1-245 mysite]$ mkdir apache
```

Below is the content of django.wsgi

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-1-245 mysite]$ vim apache/django.wsgi

import os, sys
sys.path.append('/home/ec2-user/django')
sys.path.append('/home/ec2-user/django/mysite')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi

application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Below are the permission of the files

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-1-245 django]$ cd /home/ec2-user/
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-1-245 ~]$ ls -lR django
django:
total 0
drwxrwxr-x. 4 ec2-user ec2-user 48 Sep 26 13:51 mysite

django/mysite:
total 4
drwxrwxr-x. 2 ec2-user ec2-user  24 Sep 26 13:53 apache
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 ec2-user ec2-user 249 Sep 26 13:50 manage.py
drwxrwxr-x. 2 ec2-user ec2-user  70 Sep 26 13:50 mysite

django/mysite/apache:
total 4
-rw-rw-r--. 1 ec2-user ec2-user 251 Sep 26 13:53 django.wsgi

django/mysite/mysite:
total 12
-rw-r--r--. 1 ec2-user ec2-user    0 Sep 26 13:50 __init__.py
-rw-r--r--. 1 ec2-user ec2-user 2042 Sep 26 13:50 settings.py
-rw-r--r--. 1 ec2-user ec2-user  275 Sep 26 13:50 urls.py
-rw-r--r--. 1 ec2-user ec2-user  387 Sep 26 13:50 wsgi.py
```

Below is the additional configuration added to apache config file.

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-1-245 ~]$ sudo vim /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName www.example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ec2-user/django/mysite/apache/django.wsgi

<Directory /home/ec2-user/django/mysite/apache>
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

After restarting the apache service, in the browser it threw Forbidden error.

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-1-245 ~]$ sudo service httpd restart
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl restart  httpd.service
```

Please help in solving the permission issue. Also let me know if you need any additional information.

Comment: You didn't need to create the apache/django.wsgi file - Django does it for you, in mysite/mysite/wsgi.py.

Comment: @Daniel Changing http.conf to use wsgi.py as below also gave the same error.
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
WSGIDaemonProcess exampleapp python-path=/home/ec2-user/django/mysite
WSGIProcessGroup exampleapp
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ec2-user/django/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py

<Directory /home/ec2-user/django/mysite/mysite>
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

Comment: Keeping project in home directory can lead to such issues. Watch this [presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/GrahamDumpleton/getting-started-with-modwsgi) from Graham Dumpleton to know more(specially slide 9).

Comment: @HarunPrasad yes I wasn't saying that was your problem, that's why I only posted it as a comment.

Comment: Did you run permission change code for your project folder? 'sudo chown :www-data ~/myproject'